# HoughCircles is returning false circles

Tags: opencv

I'm working on an an app that uses openCV to count the spots on dominoes and it's sometimes returning a circle when it finds the semicircle at the corner of the dominoes.  I've fiddled with the different parameters and can't get this problem fixed. Any ideas?

```
try
{
   circles = new Mat(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
   Imgproc.HoughCircles(grayMat, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp, 
   minDist, param1, param2, minRadius, maxRadius);

   numberOfCircles = (circles.rows() == 0) ? 0 : circles.cols();
}
```

This image shows the red circle at the corner of one of the dominoes:

[image: This image shows the red circle at the corner of one of the dominoes.]

Comment: Limiting the radius of the circle isn't enough? The false circles seem reasonably larger than the real circles that it might work. To deal with proportions (in case you're hard coding the radii), you could dynamically check for radii that are larger than the prevalent ones, since it doesn't seem to happen that often.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  The problem is that when there are a lot of dominoes in the image you have to hold the camera higher up and hence the diameter of the circles gets smaller in pixels.